# Using libraries to read inputstream into arrays in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, sockets, save

I am trying to save data (specifically an image) received from an input stream (from a socket) into a byte array.
I have checked two options:

a. Using `java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream`, and then use the following code:

```
  InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
  byte[] imageInBytes = in.toByteArray();
```

the problem there is that eclipse does not recognize the method `toByteArray()`. How can I copy/change the `InputStream` (in this case `in`) into a `ByteArrayOutputStream` in order to use that method?

b. Using `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils`, and then use the following:

```
    InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
    byte[] imageInBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
```

which I added commons-io-2.4.jar in the java build path and copy it in the /libs directory, but still it does not do what it suppose, and an error is given due to `byte[] imageInBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);`.

I am using gingerbread, by the way.

For both cases I was wondering whether I am doing it right, and how to fix the mentioned problem.

Comment: `InputStream.read(byte[] buffer)` ...  http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[])

Comment: The problem using InputStream.read(byte[] buffer) is that the size of the incoming stream is unknown, in order to set the size of buffer.

Comment: Check how many bytes are available on the stream in a loop => create a byte array of that size => fill the array; and chunk by chunk you'll get everything. Just figure out how to pack it. Once the InputStream.available() returns 0, exit the loop.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

OR:

```
InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, null);
imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but eclipse does not recognize BufferedImage and ImageIO for Android apps, how can I solve this issue (ie, add the respective libraries)? Also, if I get the object BufferedImage img as you posted, how to show img in an ImageView object?.